# Where are the characters in Wireshark's Packet Bytes pane?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I've just updated my Wireshark to version 4.0.1, and now, while investigating a TCP communication, I don't see any textual information anymore in the Packet Bytes pane, as you can see from this screenshot (I've drawn a red rectangle where I expect the characters to be seen):

[image]

As you can see in the right bottom angle, I seem to have a "Default" profile, whatever that means.

Do I need to do some configuration in order to see the characters, or is this a bug in Wireshark latest version?

Oh, I already have right-clicked in that pane and set the "Show text based on packet" as ASCII, as you can see:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer on [the Wireshark website](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/19792/packet-bytes-pane-not-showing-ascii-bytes/):

I've simply moved my Wireshark session to my primary monitor, which makes it work:

[image]